# Can a Puppet Master see and/or control items on Puppets?

Tags: werewolv.es

Basically, how do items and puppets interact with each other:

1. Does the Puppet Master receive items given to puppets?
2. Can the Puppet Master use items held by puppets during the night?
3. If a Puppet is holding an item and that item is stolen during the night, will the Puppet Master receive a notification telling them that they were robbed?

And maybe more, if you can think of any other interactions when writing an answer to this question.

Bonus question:

4. What happens if a Puppet is holding the Heart of Fenrir when the last wolf dies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppets are implemented in a bit of a funny way...

They are dummy accounts that join the game automatically if the Puppetmaster is in the game and they are assigned the Puppet role. For all intents and purposes the game thinks they are actual players and I receive smite warnings for them in my email inbox...

This means that the game interacts with them as if they were a normal player for most scenarios.

> Does the Puppet Master receive items given to puppets?

No

> Can the Puppet Master use items held by puppets during the night?

No

> If a Puppet is holding an item and that item is stolen during the
>   night, will the Puppet Master receive a notification telling them that
>   they were robbed?

No

> What happens if a Puppet is holding the Heart of Fenrir when the last
>   wolf dies?

An Omegawolf will be created as normal, but the player behind it will be a dummy account, the Puppetmaster will not have control over this avatar anymore.

Answer (score 1):

From my current understanding (had a talk with Kirschstein about this), I have the following answers to some of these questions.

1: The PM receives all items given to Puppets or themselves
2: The PM can use all items held by one of its three (living) avatars

The PM doesn't know which item is held by which avatar.

3: I have no clue. Makes me wonder if the notification targets the 'avatar' or the 'holder of the item'...

4: No clue as well!